# How to manage all local storages in all versions (primary, secondary storage, sd card, usb)

Tags: android, file, storage, storage-access-framework, documentfile

**Intro**

*Managing primary storage files + secondary storage files (local only):
I will list all the informations I already have and would like you to extend them or correct me so that this question hopefully becomes a overview that summarises all the main informations someone has to know before starting to work with LOCAL storages. I'm sure many people are looking for such an overview...*

**Overview**

Normally you have following storages:

- a primary storage (always directly accessible, mostly on the internal storage, but it's up to the phone manufactorer)
- a secondary storage (directly accessible for android <=4.3)
- other external storages like USB OTG for example...

**Following questions raise up:**

1. How to find out all available local storages + find out the type (primary, secondary resp. internal, sd card, usb)?
2. List all available files on the storages

   2.1 Which storages will be indexed via the `MediaStore`?

   2.2 How to get all files via the `MediaStore`?

   2.3 How to get all files without `MediaStore`?
3. How to edit files on those storages?

Most of the things I already know, mostly my questions are based on what data is indexed by the media store, how to find out which storages are available, how to identify a storage... So I post an answer that answers most of the parts and that also shows a status for each questions <=> android version pair so that it's easily visible what informations are still missing

**Status - feel free to extend/correct my answers to the questions if you know more or I'm wrong**

*Android < 4.4*

- Question 1 - partially known ✖
- Question 2.1 - unknown ✖
- Question 2.2 - known ✔
- Question 2.3 - known ✔
- Question 3 - known ✔

*Android 4.4*

- Question 1 - partially known ✖
- Question 2.1 - unknown ✖
- Question 2.2 - known ✔
- Question 2.3 - partially known ✖
- Question 3 - partially known ✖

*Android >=5*

- Question 1 - partially known ✖
- Question 2.1 - unknown ✖
- Question 2.2 - known ✔
- Question 2.3 - known ✔
- Question 3 - known ✔

Comment: Before you get down-voted and close-voted into oblivion, you might wish to rework this into Stack Overflow's question-and-answer format (see "Can I answer my own question?" in [the site documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Comment: Edited the question and posted an answer that shows what I already know...

Answer (score 1):

**----------------------------------------------**

**Android <4.4:**

**----------------------------------------------**

*1. How to find out all available local storages + find out the type (primary, secondary resp. internal, sd card, usb)? **(partially known ✖)***

I'm not sure how to distinguish between the available storage correctly... Getting the primary storage path is possible via `File primaryStorage = context.getExternalCacheDir()`. Or you can get all paths via `File[] dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);`. This will list all available paths, not sure if it will return usb storages as well or if it reliable adds sd card paths...

I actually don't know how to reliably find out which path is internal, whcih one is an sd card and which one is an usb drive

*2.1 Which storages will be indexed via the `MediaStore`? **(unknown ✖)***

I've seen that sometimes external storages are indexed and sometimes not, I'm not sure what's the default behaviour...

*2.2 How to get all files via the `MediaStore`? **(known ✔)***

Just list all files via a query on the `ContentProvider` with following `URI`: `MediaStore.<Audio,Video,Images,File>.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, depending on which data you want

*2.3 How to get all files without `MediaStore`? **(known ✔)***

On this android version you only need the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, then you can directly list all files on the external storages via the `File` class. All you need to know are the available root paths from point 1

*3. How to edit files on those storages? **(known ✔)***

Can be done directly via the `File` class if you have the above mentioned permission in your manifest.

**----------------------------------------------**

**Android 4.4:**

**----------------------------------------------**

This device is very specific, as it does not yet offer the `Storage Access Framework` but already limits the access to secondary storages!

*1. How to find out all available local storages + find out the type (primary, secondary resp. internal, sd card, usb)? **(partially known ✖)***

Basically, this should be possible in the same way as on android < 4.4...

*2.1 Which storages will be indexed via the `MediaStore`? **(unknown ✖)***

On this device only the primary storage will be indexed, correct?

*2.2 How to get all files via the `MediaStore`? **(known ✔)***

Works the same way as it worked on android < 4.4...

*2.3 How to get all files without `MediaStore`? **(partially known ✖)***

On the primary storage it works the same way as it did on android <4.4. I don't know how it works on this android version for the other local storages...

*3. How to edit files on those storages? **(partially known ✖)***

Primary storages files will be editable via the `File` class. I don't know how to get reliable write access to other storages...

**----------------------------------------------**

**Android >=5:**

**----------------------------------------------**

*1. How to find out all available local storages + find out the type (primary, secondary resp. internal, sd card, usb)? **(partially known ✖)***

Getting primary storage is possible as before. I don't know how to get a list of all other storages though. The manual way is to let the user choose the root directory of the secondary storage, sd card, usb stick like following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
```

And afterwards just remember the returned `Uri` and persist the `Uri` when getting the result from the `Storage Access Framework`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 1234)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            // get uri
            Uri treeUri = data.getData();

            // persist permissions
            final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);

            // remember the uri for having access to the storage
            // ...
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't know how to find out the type (sd card, usb) of the directory the user selected though.

All files UNDER the root path will be readable and writeable via the `DocumentFile` class.

*2.1 Which storages will be indexed via the `MediaStore`? **(unknown ✖)***

Only the primary I think. Correct?

*2.2 How to get all files via the `MediaStore`? **(known ✔)***

Works as before...

*2.3 How to get all files without `MediaStore`? **(known ✔)***

For the primary storage, it works as before as well (just via the `File` class), for the rest you HAVE to use the `Uri` for the corresponding storage that you got in point 1. Then you can use the `DocumentFile` class to get all files

*3. How to edit files on those storages? **(known ✔)***

Primary storages files will be editable via the `File` class, the rest will be editable via the `DocumentFile` (with the help of the tree `Uri` from point 1).